# How can I calculate the sum of a custom-field from several posts?

Tags: php, wordpress, sum, custom-fields

I run a running/biking website with wordpress. Now I would like to create a PHP query that returns the posts of the last 30 days. I have done that.

However, I would also like to calculate the total distance covered during these 30 days. The distance is in a custom-field called "distance".

I think it should be possible to do this somehow with "sum" - but I can't manage it. Does anyone have any ideas?

`

```
<?php
  function filter_where($where = '') {
    //posts in the last 30 days
    $where .= " AND post_date > '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-30 days')) . "'";
    return $where;
  }
add_filter('posts_where', 'filter_where');
query_posts($query_string);
?>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

in your functions.php

```
function get_total_distance(){
    
    $get_posts = get_posts(
        array(
            'numberposts' => -1,
            'date_query' => array(
                'after' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-30 days'))
            )
        )
    );
    
    $total = 0;
    
    if( $get_posts ){
        foreach( $get_posts as $post ){
            setup_postdata( $post );
            $distance = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'distance');
            if( $distance ){
                $total += $distance; 
            }
        }
    }
    
    return $total;
}
```

in your theme:

```
echo get_total_distance();
```

Comment: Hi. Thanx for this. But somehow it is not wirking yet. It doesn't return a sum.<br>
- I placed the function in function.php<br>
- for the echo i used the XYZ-snippet-plugin<br>
Normally, this works fine.
Does anybody has an idea?

Comment: is your post meta in integer format?